# Caused by : when trying to play lottie animation

Tags: android

I have error Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/loader.json when trying to play lottie animation.

As you can see in my layout xml i set auto play true so the animation should play on app up.

But i have crash with the above error.

You can find full log below xml.
How to resolve ?

BTW , the lottie's full path is : D:\Project files\MovieApp\app\src\main\assets\loader.json.
In fileName attribute i tried to set a different paths, but nothing work for me.

Here is my splash_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activities.SplashActivity">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lavLoader"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="assets/loader.json"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Log

```
2020-06-18 18:36:12.618 1436-1436/com.msapps.movieapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.msapps.movieapp, PID: 1436
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:74)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:67)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$3.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:91)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$3.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:84)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.notifyFailureListeners(LottieTask.java:158)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.access$200(LottieTask.java:27)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask$1.run(LottieTask.java:133)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/loader.json
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:388)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:362)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromAssetSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:163)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$2.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:128)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$2.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `app:lottie_fileName="assets/loader.json"` with `app:lottie_fileName="loader.json"`. Lottie looks by default in the `src/main/assets` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your file in : `src/main/res/raw`

And specify it in your xml as follows: `app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/loader"`

It works for me